# The transaction has been reverted to the initial state. Reason provided by the contract: "Amount of Ether sent should be greater than 0"

Tags: solidity

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract MyToken {
    string public name;
    string public symbol;
    uint256 public decimals;
    uint256 public totalSupply;
    uint256 public totalStakedBalance;
    uint256 public rewardRate = 300; // 3%
    uint256 public constant rewardInterval = 72 hours;
    uint256 public constant maxRewardRate = 500; // 5%
    uint256 public constant minStakeAmount = 10000000000000000;
    address[] public stakeHolders;
    uint256 public stakeRewards = 1000 * (10 ** decimals);
    uint256 public circulatingSupply = 6000 * (10 ** decimals);
    uint256 public initialSupply = 10000 * (10 ** decimals);
    uint256 public mineRewards = 10000 * (10 ** decimals);
    uint256 public airdrops = 4000 * (10 ** decimals);
    uint256 public totalTokensSold;
    uint256 public constant tokenPrice = 10000000000000000;
    address public owner;


    mapping(address => uint256) public balanceOf;
    mapping(address => mapping(address => uint256)) public allowance;
    mapping(address => bool) public isStaking;
    mapping(address => uint256) public stakeTime;
    mapping(address => uint256) public stakedBalance;
    mapping(address => uint256) public rewardBalance;
    mapping(address => uint256) public lastClaimTime;
    mapping(address => bool) hasMined;

    event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint256 value);
    event Approval(address indexed owner, address indexed spender, uint256 value);
    event Staking(address indexed staker, uint256 value);
    event Unstaking(address indexed unstaker, uint256 value);
    event OwnershipTransferred(address indexed previousOwner, address indexed newOwner);
    event RewardClaimed(address indexed user, uint256 reward);
    event RewardWithdrawn(address indexed user, uint256 reward);
    event EmergencyWithdrawal(address indexed user, uint256 reward);
    event MintAndBurn(uint256 value, uint256 initialTotalSupply, uint256 finalTotalSupply);


   constructor(string memory _name, string memory _symbol, uint256 _decimals)  {
        name = _name;
        symbol = _symbol;
        decimals = _decimals;

        balanceOf[msg.sender] = initialSupply;
        // 6000 for circulation
        balanceOf[msg.sender] = circulatingSupply;

        // 1000 for stake rewards
        balanceOf[msg.sender] += stakeRewards;

        // 1000 for mine rewards
        balanceOf[msg.sender] += mineRewards;

        // 4000 for airdrops
        balanceOf[msg.sender] += airdrops;

        totalSupply = initialSupply;
        owner = msg.sender;
    }


    modifier onlyOwner() {
        require(msg.sender == owner, "Only owner can call this function");
        _;
    }

    function transfer(address to, uint256 value) public returns (bool success) {
        
        require(balanceOf[msg.sender] >= value, "Insufficient balance");
        balanceOf[msg.sender] -= value;
        balanceOf[to] += value;
        emit Transfer(msg.sender, to, value);
        return true;
    }

    function approve(address spender, uint256 value) public returns (bool success) {
        require(msg.sender == owner);
        allowance[msg.sender][spender] = value;
        emit Approval(msg.sender, spender, value);
        return true;
    }

    function transferFrom(address from, address to, uint256 value) public returns (bool success) {
        require(msg.sender != address(0), "Invalid sender address");
        require(from != address(0), "Invalid from address");
        require(to != address(0), "Invalid to address");
        require(balanceOf[from] >= value, "Insufficient balance");
        require(allowance[from][msg.sender] >= value, "Not authorized to spend this amount");
        require(from != to, "Cannot transfer to the same address");

        balanceOf[from] -= value;
        allowance[from][msg.sender] -= value;
        balanceOf[to] += value;

        emit Transfer(from, to, value);
        return true;
    }


        function airdrop(address[] memory recipients, uint256[] memory values) public onlyOwner returns (bool success) {
        require(recipients.length == values.length, "Invalid input arrays");

        uint256 totalValue = 0;
        for (uint256 i = 0; i < recipients.length; i++) {
            require(recipients[i] != address(0), "Invalid recipient address");
            totalValue += values[i];
        }

        require(totalValue <= airdrops, "Insufficient airdrop balance");

        for (uint256 i = 0; i < recipients.length; i++) {
            transfer(recipients[i], values[i]);
        }

        airdrops -= totalValue;

        return true;
    }


   function flashMintHook() internal {
        // Perform desired operations here...
    }

    // Flash mint function
    function flashMint(uint256 value) public onlyOwner {
        uint256 initialTotalSupply = totalSupply;
        require(balanceOf[msg.sender] >= value, "Insufficient balance");

        // Ensure that the value being minted does not cause the total supply to exceed the maximum uint256 value
        require(initialTotalSupply + value <= 2**256 - 1, "Invalid total supply");

        // Mint the tokens
        totalSupply = initialTotalSupply + value;
        balanceOf[msg.sender] += value;

        // Call the hook function to perform the desired operations
        flashMintHook();

        // Burn the tokens
        uint256 finalTotalSupply = totalSupply;
        totalSupply = initialTotalSupply;
        balanceOf[msg.sender] -= value;

        emit Transfer(address(0), msg.sender, value);
        emit Transfer(msg.sender, address(0), value);
        emit MintAndBurn(value, initialTotalSupply, finalTotalSupply);
    }

    function setRewardRate(uint256 _rewardRate) public {
        require(msg.sender == owner, "Not authorized");
        require(_rewardRate <= maxRewardRate, "Exceeded maximum reward rate");
        rewardRate = _rewardRate;
    }

    function getStakedAddresses() public view returns (address[] memory) {
        return stakeHolders;
    }

    function stake(uint256 _amount) public payable returns (bool success) {
        require(_amount >= minStakeAmount, "Stake amount can't be less than minStakeAmount");
        require(balanceOf[msg.sender] >= _amount, "Insufficient balance");
        require(!isStaking[msg.sender], "Already staking");
        require(_amount > 0, "Invalid staking amount");
        balanceOf[msg.sender] -= _amount;
        stakedBalance[msg.sender] += _amount;
        totalStakedBalance += _amount;
        isStaking[msg.sender] = true;
        stakeHolders.push(msg.sender);
        stakeTime[msg.sender] = block.timestamp;
        emit Staking(msg.sender, _amount);
        return true;
    }

    function unstake(uint256 _amount) public returns (bool success) {
        require(stakedBalance[msg.sender] > 0, "No staked balance");
        require(isStaking[msg.sender], "You are not staking");
        require(stakedBalance[msg.sender] >= _amount, "Insufficient staked balance");
        uint256 stakingPeriod = block.timestamp - stakeTime[msg.sender];
        uint256 reward = (stakedBalance[msg.sender] * rewardRate * stakingPeriod) / (rewardInterval * 100);
        isStaking[msg.sender] = false;
        stakedBalance[msg.sender] -= _amount;
        totalStakedBalance -= _amount;
        balanceOf[msg.sender] += _amount + reward;
        emit Unstaking(msg.sender, _amount);
        return true;
    }

    function claimReward() public {
        require(stakedBalance[msg.sender] > 0, "No staked balance");
        uint256 timeSinceLastClaim = block.timestamp - lastClaimTime[msg.sender];
        uint256 reward = (stakedBalance[msg.sender] * rewardRate * timeSinceLastClaim) / (rewardInterval * 100);
        require(reward > 0, "No rewards available");
        rewardBalance[msg.sender] += reward;
        lastClaimTime[msg.sender] = block.timestamp;
        emit RewardClaimed(msg.sender, reward);
    }

    function withdrawRewards() public {
        require(rewardBalance[msg.sender] > 0, "No rewards available");
        uint256 rewardAmount = rewardBalance[msg.sender];
        rewardBalance[msg.sender] = 0;
        stakeRewards -= rewardAmount; // deduct reward from contract balance
        balanceOf[msg.sender] += rewardAmount;
        emit RewardWithdrawn(msg.sender, rewardAmount);
    }


    function emergencyWithdraw() public {
        require(stakedBalance[msg.sender] > 0, "No staked balance");
        uint256 stakedAmount = stakedBalance[msg.sender];
        stakedBalance[msg.sender] = 0;
        totalStakedBalance -= stakedAmount;
        balanceOf[msg.sender] += stakedAmount;
        emit EmergencyWithdrawal(msg.sender, stakedAmount);
    }

    function transferOwnership(address newOwner) public onlyOwner {
        require(newOwner != address(0), "Invalid address");
        emit OwnershipTransferred(owner, newOwner);
        owner = newOwner;
    }

    function burn(uint256 value) public onlyOwner returns (bool success) {
        require(balanceOf[msg.sender] >= value, "Insufficient balance");
        totalSupply -= value;
        balanceOf[msg.sender] -= value;
        emit Transfer(msg.sender, address(0), value);
        return true;
    }

    uint256 constant MINING_INTERVAL = 3 days;
    // Set the maximum number of tokens that can be minted
    uint256 constant MAX_SUPPLY = 1000 * 10**18;
    // Set the percentage of tokens to be minted at each mining interval
    uint256 constant INFLATION_RATE = 1;
    // Set the time of the last mining for each user
    mapping(address => uint256) lastMiningTime;

    function mine() public returns (bool) {
        // Ensure that the user has not already mined in the current mining interval
        require(!hasMined[msg.sender], "You have already mined in this interval");

        // Ensure that the user has waited at least MINING_INTERVAL since their last mining
        require(lastMiningTime[msg.sender] + MINING_INTERVAL <= block.timestamp, "You must wait before mining again");

        // Update the last mining time and hasMined for the user
        lastMiningTime[msg.sender] = block.timestamp;
        hasMined[msg.sender] = true;

        // Calculate the number of tokens to mint based on the inflation rate
        uint256 tokensToMint = (totalSupply * INFLATION_RATE) / 100;

        // Ensure that the total supply does not exceed the maximum supply
        require(totalSupply + tokensToMint <= MAX_SUPPLY, "Maximum supply exceeded");

        // Subtract the mined tokens from the mine rewards and send them to the miner
        uint256 minedTokens = (mineRewards * INFLATION_RATE) / 1000;
        mineRewards -= minedTokens;
        balanceOf[msg.sender] += minedTokens;

        // Mint the tokens and update the total supply
        totalSupply += tokensToMint;

        // Emit the transfer event
        emit Transfer(address(0), msg.sender, minedTokens);
        emit Transfer(address(0), msg.sender, tokensToMint);

        // Return success
        return true;
    }
    
    function buyTokens(uint256 tokensToBuy) public payable {
        require(msg.value > 0, "Amount of Ether sent should be greater than 0");

        uint256 totalTokens = tokensToBuy *(10**18);
        uint256 tokensLeft = initialSupply - totalTokensSold;

        require(tokensLeft >= totalTokens, "Insufficient tokens left for sale");
        uint256 costInWei = tokenPrice * totalTokens;
        require(costInWei <= msg.value, "Insufficient Ether sent");

        // Calculate any excess wei sent and refund it to the buyer
        uint256 refund = msg.value - costInWei;
        if (refund > 0) {
            payable(msg.sender).transfer(refund);
        }

        // Update total number of tokens sold and transfer tokens to buyer
        totalTokensSold += totalTokens;
        balanceOf[msg.sender] += totalTokens;
        emit Transfer(address(this), msg.sender, totalTokens);

        // Deduct tokens purchased from the initial supply
        initialSupply -= totalTokens;
    }




    mapping(address => uint256) public votes;
    mapping(address => address) public hasVoted;

    function vote(address candidate) public returns (bool success) {
        require(candidate != address(0), "Invalid candidate address");
        require(balanceOf[msg.sender] >= 1, "Insufficient balance");
        require(candidate != msg.sender, "You cannot vote for yourself");
        require(hasVoted[msg.sender] != candidate, "You have already voted for this candidate");

        votes[candidate] += 1;
        hasVoted[msg.sender] = candidate;
        balanceOf[msg.sender] -= 1;
        emit Transfer(msg.sender, address(0), 1);
        return true;
    }

    function getVoteCount(address candidate) public view returns (uint256 count) {
        require(candidate != address(0), "Invalid candidate address");
        return votes[candidate];
    }

}
```

The buyToken function is flagging error when I call it with an amount.

Comment: please help me test the code on remix too, and see what I'm doing wrong, I'm new to solidity

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that you're only specifying the number of tokens you want to buy but not sending the required amount of ether to make the purchase.
If you're testing on Remix, you need to input a value in the following field:

[image]

After inputting the value there, then you can execute the function.
I hope this helps!

Comment: thanks man it worked! thanks man!!!